# How to create function that displays each sprite in an array, pausing in between?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

From what I've read Unity doesn't support gifs natively, so I'm trying to create a simple function to create a script manually. I'm trying to do something along the lines of this.

```
IEnumerator AnimationGif(Sprite[] gifArray, float timeBetweenFrames)
{
    Corner.sprite = gifArray[0];
    foreach (Sprite x in gifArray)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timeBetweenFrames);
        Corner.sprite = gifArray[x];
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

As is, gifArray[x] has the error cannot convert type UnityEngine.Sprite to int. I'm sure it's a simple syntax error but what do I need to do to have the function display each sprite in an array while pausing in between?

Comment: `x` is a `Sprite` in your array, not an index of your array. `Corner.sprite = x;` will get rid of the error. Also, the way you have it written, it will do the 0th sprite twice. You should remove `Corner.sprite = gifArray[0]` and put the `yield` statement at the end of the `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from here:

```
Corner.sprite = gifArray[x];
```

*It seems like you're confusing `for` loop with `foreach` loop.* You are using `Sprite` as index to access array of Sprite but `int` is used to access each individual item in an array.

You would have been able to do this with a `for` loop then use the `int` to access the values:

```
public Image Corner;

IEnumerator AnimationGif(Sprite[] gifArray, float timeBetweenFrames)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gifArray.Length; x++)
    {
        Corner.sprite = gifArray[x];
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timeBetweenFrames);
    }
}
```

If you want to use `foreach` loop, the temporary variable created in each loop should be used directly. You don't have to access it directly with an index:

```
public Image Corner;

IEnumerator AnimationGif(Sprite[] gifArray, float timeBetweenFrames)
{
    foreach (Sprite x in gifArray)
    {
        Corner.sprite = x;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timeBetweenFrames);
    }
}
```